# Actionsctipt: Creating a Movie Clips inside a class

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript

I'm trying to draw an movie clip object from within a class and directly output it onto the screen. Needless to say, I'm fairly new to actionscript. This is my class:

```
class Class.player {
  function create() {
    _root.createEmptyMovieClip("ship", _root.getNextHighestDepth());
    ship._x = 200;
    ship._y = 390;
    ship.beginFill(0xFF00AA);
    ship.moveTo(-20, -12);
    ship.lineTo(20, -12);
    ship.lineTo(20, 12);
    ship.lineTo(-20, 12);
    ship.lineTo(-20, -12);
    ship.endFill();
  }
}
```

And this is the code I'm using to import, call, and execute it.

```
import Class.player;
var Player:player = new player();
Player.create();
```

There's no error message, and it works fine if I place the create function into the main script, but nothing happens if I call it from within the class.

Any advice would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend reading this post to help you: http://brianchau.wordpress.com/2008/01/15/targeting-movieclip-from-an-as3-class-file/

The main code from the website is :

```
package
{
 import flash.display.MovieClip;

 public class Test extends MovieClip
 {
  public static var blackbox_mc:MovieClip = new BlackBox();

  public function Test()
  {
   this.stage.addChild(blackbox_mc);
   var myTest:Control = new Control();
  }
 }
}
```

Create the Control.as class file with the following code:

```
package
{
 public class Control
 {
  public function Control()
  {
   Test.blackbox_mc.y = 100;
  }
 }
}
```

The trick is to create a static variable so that it can be referenced from the Control.as file.